# Check if a user is assigned to more than one meeting in two consecutive days

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have a table of meetings and participants of those meetings:

```
 id | callid | participants |    date    
----+--------+--------------+------------
  1 |      1 | {1,2}        | 2020-05-30
  2 |      2 | {1,2}        | 2020-05-01
  3 |      3 | {3,4}        | 2020-03-10
```

I created the following query to isolate the reviewer_id and the dates of their meeting:

```
select *
      from (select r.id as reviewer_id, m.date as meeting_date
            from researcher r, meeting m
            where r.id = any (m.participants)
            order by r.id) u;
```

which gives table:

```
 reviewer_id | meeting_date 
-------------+--------------
           1 | 2020-05-30
           1 | 2020-05-01
           2 | 2020-05-30
           2 | 2020-05-01
           3 | 2020-03-10
           4 | 2020-03-10
```

Now, this is the part where I'm stuck. How can I use this to determine if a reviewer is attending more than one meeting in two consecutive days?

I have tried using the PostgreSQL `datediff()` function:

```
select u.reviewer_id, u.meeting_date, date_part('day', u.meeting_date - row_number() over(order by u.meeting_date))
      from (select r.id as reviewer_id, m.date as meeting_date
            from researcher r, meeting m
            where r.id = any (m.participants)
            order by r.id) u;
```

but it keeps saying:

```
operator does not exist: date - bigint
```

If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the sample output of above table.?

Comment: @flutterbug98. . . Is there a reason you don't use `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `row_number()` outputs a `bigint`. There is an operator `-(date, integer)`, so all you need to do is cast the `bigint` to `integer`:

```
u.meeting_date - CAST(row_number() over(order by u.meeting_date) AS integer)
```

I think you are looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT reviewer_id
FROM (SELECT r.id AS reviewer_id,
             m.date - 1 =
                lag(m.date) OVER (PARTITION BY r.id ORDER BY m.date)
                AS twice_in_a_row
      FROM researcher r
         JOIN meeting m
            ON r.id = ANY (m.participants)) AS q
WHERE twice_in_a_row;
```

Comment: Okay, so it does now work. But my implementation is incorrect. How could I use the date_part() function to determine if a reviewer has been assigned to more than one meeting in two consecutive days?

Comment: I have added how such a query could look.